# Is it counted as in-app payment if Paypal cart is opened as web page?

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm struggling on the payment options to make available on my Android app (4.0+) distributed through Google Play. If I add Paypal as an option in the app, and selecting it will redirect user to the Paypal cart to be opened on a third-party browser, will it be considered a method of in-app payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this does not answer the question in it's entirety, I would like to point out a rather important point.

If you are intend to use *in-app purchasing* integrating PayPal, you cannot distribute your application via Google Play. If you distribute it through other channels, then it is an entirely different thing.

Check the [Google Play Developer Program Policies](http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html).

And this, http://www.insidemobileapps.com/2012/07/31/google-drops-the-hammer-on-third-party-android-billing-services-apps-must-use-googles-billing-system/

Of course, as already pointed out by *BenjiWiebe*, from a purely technical point of view, it ***should*** not be considered as an in-app payment. The risk lies in Users flagging the application on Google Play.

So, if the rewards are worth the risk....